# Using static file cross-site in umbraco backoffice

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Is there a way to include a css/js file in the umbraco backoffice which I need to use in the whole site(not in a single plugin)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Umbraco backoffice main View is usually located in your project folder under:

`$YourSolutionFolder\ProjectFolder\umbraco\Views\Default.cshtml`

In that file you can insert a link to your external CSS or JS as follows:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/theme.css">`

`<script src="~/scripts/script.js"></script>`

Note: Bear in mind that you can have some CSS conflicts overriding some Umbraco styles when using your own custom CSS file.